# Grafana how view only NUll values

Tags: grafana, monitoring

Tell me about Grafana, please. I have a graph with pings of connections by endpoints on which there are gaps in pings that are highlighted as Null?
I tried to use the vector function to make null a negative value. But it doesn't work.
You need to see only null values in a separate graph????????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.